# String variable null

Tags: c#

Why
`string str = null; Console.Write(str);`
returns blank, but
`string str = null; Console.Write(str.length);`
returns null reference exception?

String is a reference type, so it can hold null, but why don't `Console.Write(str)` return null reference exception too? Connection with heap data is lost so we can't call for that data.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` has its own logic of handling `null`. Why shouldn't it? However accessing something on a null-reference is completely unrelated to `Console.WriteLine`. The same would happen if you just assigned `str.Length` to a variable. What do you mean by " Connection with heap data is lost so we can't call for that data."?

Comment: ["Why *doesn't* X happen" is a rather unclear question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293815/5133585). What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textwriter.cs,286

Comment: Null reference exception occurs when you try to access a property of `str` which is null.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain Assigning null to a reference type we don't have access to a data stored in a heap, don't we?

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing apples with lemons. First off `Console.WriteLine` *has* some built-in logic for handling `null`. This avoids the exception in the first place, as throwing exceptions for program-flow is usually considered bad practice.

On the other hand it's *not* `Console.WriteLine` that throws the null-reference-exception, it's the property-access `str.Length` that does. The exact same would happen if you'd just assign that value to a variable:

```
var a = str.Length;
```

So asking "why doesn't `WriteLine` throw" is pointless, as the function isn't even related to the exception.

You can avoid the exception in the first place by checking for null` yourself, e.g. using the [null-conditional-operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)

```
Console.WriteLine(str?.Length)
```

which effectivly is the same as this:

```
if(str == null)
    Console.WriteLine(null);
else
    Console.WriteLine(str.Length);
```

(disclaimer: actually not the same, as the operator is short-circuiting, however)

Comment: It wasn't a question "why Console.Write throws" it was more like "why the result of the following code is".

Comment: @coldheart so you're asking: "why does `WriteLine` write an ampty string? That's a fairly opinion-based question, of course designers of C# could have make the function just throw an `ArgumentNullException`. However they just didn't for whatever reasons .

Answer (score 0):

`Console.Write()` is using the `System.IO.TextWriter` and its overloaded `Write` method:

```
    // Writes a string to the text stream. If the given string is null, nothing
    // is written to the text stream.
    //
    public virtual void Write(string? value)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            Write(value.ToCharArray());
        }
    }
```

That's why you get blank.

Your null-exception error comes from accessing a property of a null-reference.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Write' method at the end level uses the 'Write' method of the 'TextWriter' class. In the following you can see this method:

```
    public virtual void Write(string value)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            Write(value.ToCharArray());
        }
    }
```

As you can see, if the value is null, no exception would throw.

Answer (score 0):

Why `Console.Write(null)` returns blank?

The method is defined to write blank if the input is null. See the reference [link](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textwriter.cs,5238cceaebfeaa74)

[image]

Why `str.Length;` give NullReferenceException?

By using the above line of code, you are asking the compiler to get the value of `Length` property of the variable `str`. But the property itself is `null` then how he reads the property? so Its throwing the exception.

Comment: The source-code doesn't answer the question "why" it's designed like that. It could be written otherwise, which is completely up to Microsoft's decisions.